# how do I call js script from angular button

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to call this script `<script src="products/products_list.js"></script>` each time when I click on 'Add Button'.

Currently, this script is being called only once when the page load.

html code

**test.html**

```
<div class="col-md-1 form-group"><br/>
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Button" ng-click="packageCtrl.add(rlCtrl)" ng-disabled="packageCtrl.disableAdd()"/>
                        </div>

 <script src="products/products_list.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever is in that script needs to be placed in a function. Then a call to that function can be made in the click handler for that button.

My best guess is that whatever is in that JS file is just inline code that is being executed immediately upon load. If you want that code to be executed at specific times, it needs to be placed in a event handler to be executed when that event occurs.

Ultimately, you are not providing enough information to truly answer this questions.

Comment: that script is just calling another js script. I will attach that script